# Primefaces ViewScoped

Tags: jsf, primefaces, view-scope

I want my managed bean to be cleared after a successful action. I use PrimeFaces5.0 for web page. Here is a block. I used partialSubmit and process to submit only one part of the form.

```
<p:panel id="panel1">
  ...
    <p:commandButton id="saveButton" value="Save"
        action="#{myBean.save}" 
        update="msg" partialSubmit="true" process="panel1" />
</p:panel>
```

I used @viewScoped for managed bean and my save method is

```
public String save() {
    //do some save stuff
    try{
        myEjb.save();
        return "";
    } catch (EJBException ejbe) {
        mesajYazKaydetmeHatali(ejbe);
        ejbe.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
 }
```

Although I return "" after a successful save, I think PF does not refresh the page. How can I achieve this.

Thanks

Comment: i'm glad. i'll write it as a separate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

instead of returning an empty string, you can redirect the user to the same page in case of successful save:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().redirect(redirectionPath‌​);
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know did i undestand clearly your quesiton, i think that you want to refresh page after saving a new record. You can use request context

With spesifying your tag id you can update needed thing, if you want to refresh your panel you can use the code below.

```
context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
context.update("YOURFORMID:panel1");
```